# Best solution to backup file subset on a remote Windows web server to a local windows web server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have an internal web server (win08) which I'd like to configure as a backup server for a live web server (also Win08).

I'd like to do full and incremental backups from the local machine where it pulls from the live web server on a daily basis.

I see lots of tools for unix based machines for this. Are there any good tools native and optimised for windows based websites/servers?

I only want a subset of files (approx. 8GB) rather than a full machine image.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [bacula](http://www.bacula.org)? It is a free backup solution for Windows and Unix-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) for backing up your subset of files.